# Deploying an windowsform client app but assemblys are missing

Tags: visual-studio, assemblies, gac

I'm trying to finish a little module from a reporting app using external dlls. I'm putting the files into the bin folder but when I deploy the app with ClickOnce, and the install finishes, I see that all external dlls are missing. For example, the `Microsoft.SqlServer.Types version 10.0.0.0` is missing.

Is there a way to install these assemblies automatically in the client GAC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution : when using click once, go to project propertyes, then to Deploy tab and in requireds files select "included" for any assembly that you have already referenced in your project or Fx